# SP-API OAuth : 'Something went wrong. Unable to find application.'

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I created the login with Amazon link ( https://sellercentral.amazon.com/apps/authorize/consent?application_id=lwa_app_id&state=stateexample&version=beta ) but when I try to login with the seller account I receive this error: [SP-API OAuth error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4es8.jpg)

I mention that the application is in draft mode.

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: My mistake was that I used the ID from the "LWA credentials" page. But the real App Client ID is on the "developer console" page, in the first column of the table that lists your apps.